# Stop NSPopover Opening Multiple Times

Tags: nsviewcontroller, nspopover

I have an NSButton that, when clicked, opens an NSPopover, my only problem is that when the button is clicked again, the NSPopover opens again on top of the other one, the pop over is opened using:

```
- (IBAction)openSettingsPopover:(id)sender {
    NSViewController *controller = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:nil];
    NSPopover *popover = [[NSPopover alloc] init];
    [popover setContentSize:NSMakeSize(288.0f, 170.0f)];
    [popover setContentViewController:controller];
    [popover setAnimates:YES];
    [popover showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMaxXEdge];
}
```

How would I go about dismissing the popover rather than opening another one, same for if the user clicks outside the view? Thanks in advance.

[image: (left = clicked once, right = clicked multiple times)]

Answer (score 3):

Keep a reference to the NSPopover instance, check if it's not-nil before opening a new one

```
- (IBAction)openSettingsPopover:(id)sender {
    if (self.settingsPopover) {
        // Close it when clicked again, or simply return
        [self.settingsPopover close];
    }

    self.settingsPopover = [[NSPopover alloc] init];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An easier way is to change it's behavior.
Just set the behavior property to NSPopOverBehaviourTransient and when the user interacts with another UI element not in the popover it will be dismissed.

```
[popover setBehaviour:NSPopOverBehaviourTransient];
```

Comment: This is by no mean a solution, as the OP's problem is he creates _new_ popover each time the action gets called.